# Send Argument To A Search Box In A Website And Receive Results Using Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, post

I have a website That Contain a Search Box, i need to send an argument from the terminal to this search box,and then submit the search button, and get the results of the other page, i'am using `curl`, but i don't know how to get the results or how to click the submit button, here is my script for now :

```
echo -n "Enter The Number You Want: " 
read Term

curl -d "{\"Term\" : \"$Term\"}" www.example.com > ~/Desktop/Curl/form-response.html
```

Comment: How about using something like [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/)?

Comment: i'am forced to stick with a shell script

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your html form action url and method if GET or POST.
You have to curl the *action url* (not the url of the form, as I suppose) adding parameter like

?p1=val1&p2=val2

if GET or use -d or -F if POST

Use -o outputfile instead of > outputfile

Comment: echo -n "Enter What You Want: " 
read sperm

curl -F www.example.com\s=\"Term\" : \"$sperm\" -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: ix_token=98ff1652-11c8-4d7b-b10a-2ac3a64bb426; sc_is_visitor_unique=rx11735356.1578932483.8D6CE69F90C04F89218A3CA51443E4E4.3.3.3.1.1.1.1.1.1' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' > form-response.html

Comment: this is the update of my curl but i only receive the html of the page i need the results now

Comment: I am sure you need a ? after www.example.com, like www.example.com?s=Term but I do not know if the rest is ok. Try submitting the form with a graphic browser and use that url